# change selected switch track color

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a switch and when it's toggled on, I want the track color to be orange, and if it's toggled off, I want it to be grey. However, I don't want to mess up the sizing of the existing thumb.xml and track.xml files.

custom_thumb.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

custom_track.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="60dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/cold_grey06" />
</shape>
```

switch

```
<Switch
                android:id="@+id/rememberSwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"
                android:track="@drawable/custom_track" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a color resource in `res/color` folder, for example `track_color.xml`:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/orange"/>
    <item android:color="@color/cold_grey06"/>
</selector>
```

And then use it in the `custom_track.xml`:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="60dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/track_color" />
</shape>
```

Comment: color.xml is drawable but you wrote it this way 
<solid android:color="@color/track_color" />

Comment: <solid android:color="@drawable/track_color" /> 
bu şekilde olacak

Comment: `track_color.xml` is a color resource, not drawable

Comment: you simply create a resource with *Color* resource type and paste my first code snippet, you may only need to change *orange* with your resource name

Comment: <solid android:color="@drawable/track_color" /> 
actually this worked

Comment: @ÖmerSeyfettinYavuzyiğit is your `track_color` in the *drawable* folder?

Comment: Yes there. track_color

Comment: I don't have color in the resource

Comment: That's the reason it worked in your case. You put the resource in the `res/drawable` folder so you can only address it with `@drawable/...`. In my answer it's in the `res/color` folder, that's why I addressed it with `@color/...`. Both ways technically work

Comment: Can you rate my question?

Comment: done :) can you rate my answer then?